# error C2664 : 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty&&)': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Node<T> *' to 'Node<T>&&'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c2664

error C2664 : 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty&&)': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Node *' to 'Node&&'

please I need help...

I created node.h & heap.h

node.h :

```
#ifndef __NODE_H_
#define __NODE_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node {
private:
    Node<T>* m_brother;
    int m_index;
    T m_data;

public:
    Node (T data);
    ~Node ();
    int GetIndex () const; 
    int GetBrother () const;
    void SetIndex (const int index);
    void SetBrother (const Node<T>* brother);
    void SetData (const T& data);
    bool operator<(const Node<T>& other) const;
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data) {
    SetData(data);
}

template <class T>
int Node<T>::GetIndex () const {
    return m_index;
}


template <class T>
int Node<T>::GetBrother () const {
    return m_brother->GetIndex();
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::SetData (const T& data) {
    m_data = data;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::SetBrother(const Node<T>* brother) {
    m_brother = brother;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::SetIndex(const int index) {
    if (index > 0)
        m_index = index;
    else
        cout <<"ERROR: Index Can't be negative number!"<<endl;
}

template <class T>
bool Node<T>:: operator<(const Node<T>& other)const
{
    return *(this->GetData()) > *(other.GetData());
}

#endif



heap.h:

#ifndef __HEAP_H_
#define __HEAP_H_
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Heap {
public:
    Heap();
    virtual ~Heap();
    Node<T> * CreateNode (T data);
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    Node<T>* RemoveNode(int indexNode);
    Node<T>* ExtractMin ();
    //void AddToHeap(Node<T>* newNode);
    //void Add(int indexNode);
    void Insert(Node<T>* newNode);
    void DecreaseKey (Node<T>* newNode);
    void Exchange (int indexNode1, int indexNode2);
    void MinHeapify (int indexNode);


private:
    vector<Node<T>> m_heap;
    int num;
};


template<class T> 
Heap<T>::Heap() {

} 

template<class T> 
Heap<T>::~Heap() {
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Heap<T>::CreateNode(T data) {
    Node<T*>* node(T);
    return node;
}

template<class T> 
bool Heap<T>::IsEmpty() const {
    return (m_heap.size() == 0);
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Heap<T>::RemoveNode (int indexNum) {
    Node<T>* nodeToRemove=NULL;
    if (indexNum > 0 && indexNum < m_heap.size()) {
    nodeToRemove = m_heap[indexNum];
    m_heap [indexNum] = m_heap [ m_heap.size()-1];
    m_heap [m_heap.size()-1] = nodeToRemove;
    m_heap.pop_back();
    MinHeapify(nodeToRemove->GetIndex());
    }
    return nodeToRemove;
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::Insert(Node<T>* newNode) {
    if (m_heap.size() == 0) {
        m_heap.push_back(newNode);
    }
    else
        DecreaseKey(newNode);       
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::DecreaseKey(Node<T>* newNode) {
    m_heap.push_back(newNode);
    int index = m_heap.size();
    while ((index > 0) && (m_heap[(index/2)-1] > m_heap[index-1])) {
        Exchange(index,index/2);
        index = index/2;
    }
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Heap<T>::ExtractMin () {
    Node<T>* minNode;
    minNode = m_heap[0];
    m_heap[0] = m_heap[m_heap.size()-1];
    m_heap.erase(m_heap[m_heap.size()-1]);
    MinHeapify (0);
    return minNode;
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::Exchange (int indexNode1, int indexNode2) {
    Node<T>* tmp = m_heap[indexNode1-1];
    m_heap[indexNode1-1] = m_heap [indexNode2-1];
    m_heap[indexNode2-1] = tmp;
}


template<class T>
void Heap<T>::MinHeapify (int indexNode) {
    int leftNode = 2*indexNode;
    int rightNode = 2*indexNode+1;
    int smallest = indexNode;
    if ((leftNode <  m_heap.size()-1) && (m_heap[leftNode-1]<m_heap[smallest-1]))
        smallest = leftNode;
    if ((rightNode <  m_heap.size()-1) && (m_heap[rightNode-1]<m_heap[smallest-1]))
        smallest = rightNode;
    if (smallest != indexNode) {
        Exchange (indexNode,smallest);
        MinHeapify(smallest);
    }
}


#endif;
```

In the main, I tried to check and it didn't compiled.

```
int main () {
Node<Vehicle*> a(car1);
Heap<Vehicle*> heap;
Node<Vehicle*>* p = &a;
heap.Insert(p);
return 0;
}
```

why?

Comment: Names with double underscores (your include guards) are [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), don't use them.

Comment: @GMan - better still, use '#pragma once'

Comment: @Steve: Though that's implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Heap<T>::Insert` function takes a `Node<T*>*`.

`m_heap` is defined as a `vector<Node<T>>`.  You need to insert a `Node<T*>`, not a `Node<T*>*`.  `Heap<T>::Insert` should take its parameter by const reference, not by pointer.

Your code uses a lot of pointers unnecessarily; it would be much simpler if you dealt with references and returned things by value rather than tangling with pointers all over the place.